# Combine tapply to create a matrix

Tags: r, tapply

I need to create a matrix with the columns (Swing, Blues, Contra) and Rows (M, F) using Ht data from a `data.frame`.

I need to create a matrix of NA values and then fill the matrix by row using the outcome from each tapply function.

It needs to look like this:

```
    Swing    Blues   Contra
M    174.6   186.8   194.5
F    177.7    178    180.4
```

The 2 tapply functions I have are:

```
 tapply(dancenewM$Ht,dancenewM$Type,mean)
 tapply(dancenewF$Ht,dancenewF$Type,mean)
```

sample data:

```
  Sex Type   Ht
  F   Swing  177.9 
  F   Swing  177.5 
  F   Contra 179.6 
  F   Contra 181.3 
  F   Blues  179.7 
  F   Blues  176.3 
  M   Swing  172.7  
  M   Swing  176.5 
  M   Contra 194.6
  M   Contra 194.4  
  M   Blues  193.4 
  M   Blues  180.2 "))
```

Any help with this would be greatly appreciated.

Answer (score 1):

We can use `tapply` with grouping variables as 'sex' and 'Type' to get the `mean` of 'Ht'.

```
with(df1, tapply(Ht, list(Sex = Sex, Type), FUN= mean))

# Sex Blues Contra Swing
#   F 178.0 180.45 177.7
#   M 186.8 194.50 174.6
```

---

Or we can use `data.table`

```
library(data.table)
dcast(setDT(df1), Sex~Type, value.var='Ht', mean)
#    Sex Blues Contra Swing
# 1:   F 178.0 180.45 177.7
# 2:   M 186.8 194.50 174.6
```

#### data

```
df1 <- structure(list(Sex = structure(c(1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 2L, 
2L, 2L, 2L, 2L, 2L), .Label = c("F", "M"), class = "factor"), 
    Type = structure(c(3L, 3L, 2L, 2L, 1L, 1L, 3L, 3L, 2L, 2L, 
    1L, 1L), .Label = c("Blues", "Contra", "Swing"), class = "factor"), 
    Ht = c(177.9, 177.5, 179.6, 181.3, 179.7, 176.3, 172.7, 176.5, 
    194.6, 194.4, 193.4, 180.2)), .Names = c("Sex", "Type", "Ht"
), class = "data.frame", row.names = c(NA, -12L))
```

Comment: It runs, but it still doesn't separate out the Males and Females. I just get the overall mean.

Comment: @Vixxen81  Based on the example I created, it is separating out the 'Males' and 'Females'.  You didn't provide any input example.  So, if you can provide some input example and then comment, it might make more sense.

Comment: @Vixxen81  Why don't you update your post with an example?

Comment: Sorry, I'm trying to. Thanks.

Comment: @Vixxen81  Okay, I have to go now.  WIll check it later.

Comment: @Vixxen81 akrun's code works for the example you gave `with(df1, tapply(Ht, list(Sex, Type), FUN= mean))`

Comment: So, this how I need to do it. I need to create a matrix of NA values and then fill the matrix by row using the outcome from each tapply function.

Comment: @Vixxen81 I'm not sure I understand, doesn't akrun's solution give you your desired results?